# Is it possible to have meta questions appear in the main question feed?

Tags: feature-request, meta, feed

This is to encourage more users to participate in meta. I'm asking whether it is both technically possible and whether it is appropriate:

Since meta questions are relatively few, is it possible to have them appear among the regular questions, perhaps marked with an icon or a special color? (I usually go to meta by clicking the link on the top menu bar, which I don't always do. Having updates appear on the main page may make a difference for those like me).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this would be constructive. It would create duplicate information. There is already an RSS feed that you can subscribe to and the chat Mos Esley has both main site questions and meta questions posted as they are asked.

Comment: I understand, but I'm not sure how many users (except us fanatics) would check three places on the same site on a regular basis. I myself didn't do this until recently.

Comment: @HNL Checking only two places would be sufficient. The RSS feed is redundant to the one-box listings of normal and meta questions in chat.